# Quiero hacer un select de un query que se despliegue en consola

Tags: c#

Lo que busco hacer es desplegar en pantalla de consola las tres variables ID,Clientes,cantidad que los primeros 2 tienen valores fijos en la tabla,pero con el valor cantidad despliega el numero de filas que contiene cada cliente por lo que no puede ser un valor fijo ya que se estara actualizando cada vez que se repita el while

Pero aparece esta excepcion System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.'

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                int total = 0;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select iCatalogo As ID, esquema As Cliente From  Keia.[vishistoricos('UsuarDB','Usuarios DB','Español')] WHERE dtfinvigencia>=getdate()  ORDER BY  esquema", con);
                 //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", 1);
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    using (var conn2 = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                    {
                        conn2.Open();

                        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) From " + rdr[1].ToString() + ".[visdetallados('detall','detallecdr','español')] Where fechainicio>='2019-12-01' and fechainicio<='2019-12-03' ", conn2);
                        SqlDataReader drTotal = comando.ExecuteReader();

                        total = Convert.ToInt32(drTotal[0]);
                    }

                    listEjemploModel.Add(new EjemploModel
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]),
                        Cliente = rdr[1].ToString(),
                        Cantidad = total
                    });  
                }
```

```html
<
```

Comment: En que linea, te tira el error?

Comment: No deberias hacer una subconsulta o un having o groupby para no realizar dos consultas solo para en la segunda traer el count de la primera?